# Should we allow subjective questions?

Tags: discussion

Some questions here are asking for factual answers:

- [How long was Jesus in the tomb?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-long-was-jesus-in-the-tomb)
- [Where does the Bible stand on vegetarianism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64/where-does-the-bible-stand-on-vegetarianism)
- [Do animals have souls?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/185/do-animals-have-souls) (the question states a Biblical answer is expected)

Some are not, but appear to be asking for advice / opinions:

- [How Christians should meditate?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-christians-should-meditate)
- [Can I believe in evolution and still be a Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/130/can-i-believe-in-evolution-and-still-be-a-christian)
- [Is it true that teachings that contradicts the 66 books of the traditional Bible Canon is Surely Wrong?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/169/is-it-true-that-teachings-that-contradicts-the-66-books-of-the-traditional-bible)

My question is: is the second kind (subjective) type of question welcome here?

The reason for asking is that they are generally not welcome on other Stack Exchange sites. Are they welcome here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subjective questions are prevalent across the SE network on most sites that aren't targeted at a technical profession. There is no reason we should stay away from subjectivity just because we can be a contentious lot.

However, the important thing is to stick to the criteria laid out in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). And to keep the image Jeff always links to in mind [image].

If we can keep to those two criteria in mind then I think that we can successfully accept subjective questions.

Comment: +1.  Agreed 100%